# wifi not working when connect ethernet port ubuntu server, operate internet(wifi) and LAN (eth) at same time

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet, ethernet

I have searched for the same issue and there were some similar but none of the solutions worked for me.

I have a PC running ubuntu server 22.04.3 it has a wifi adapter set at

```
192.168.1.111
```

I can reach that through SSH all working ok.

I setup a ethernet connection with the ip address 192.168.2.22 using

```
/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

and I have a camera with 192.168.2.64

when I am connected through wifi  and connect the ethernet lead it disconnects the wifi and stays disconnected.

presently I am connecting in through ssh via ethernet, but I need to be able to reach the internet.

so I have tried,

check in bios for anthing releated to wifi/ethernet there was not any releatable settings.

checked the routes under ipv4 tab in net manager so that the option 'use this connection only for resources on its own network" checked the connections file

```
[connection]
id=Ethernet connection 1
uuid=8eac2307-8e13-4dca-ae46-d45552704db5
type=ethernet
interface-name=enp2s0

[ethernet]
mac-address=64:00:6A:16:A5:66

[ipv4]
address1=192.168.2.22/24
method=manual
never-default=true

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=ignore

[proxy]
```

When configuring my ethernet static address I have not configured a default gateway as it tells me a gateway is not compatiable with 'never default'

Ive made the prority of the WIFI connection higher.

Is there any other trouble shooting I should try?

ifconfig

```
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:99ff:fea7:7a72  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:99:a7:7a:72  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 43  bytes 6487 (6.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.22  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::6600:6aff:fe16:a566  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 64:00:6a:16:a5:66  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 709  bytes 68874 (68.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 567  bytes 67735 (67.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 228  bytes 20303 (20.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 228  bytes 20303 (20.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vetha1df66d: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::9476:cbff:fe3f:7c70  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 96:76:cb:3f:7c:70  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 74  bytes 10522 (10.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.111  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::f70b:d185:5201:b9f2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a4:c4:94:38:f2:de  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 240  bytes 22054 (22.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 86  bytes 11016 (11.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

when logged in with the GUI the ether net connecyton is showing never used even though I am using it to SSH to the server.

[etherner never used?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKY8s.jpg)

ip a s -

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:00:6a:16:a5:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.110/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.22/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6600:6aff:fe16:a566/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a4:c4:94:38:f2:de brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.111/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f70b:d185:5201:b9f2/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:04:6a:8b:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:4ff:fe6a:8be6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: veth45f0596@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether ba:4b:4b:c8:ae:df brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::b84b:4bff:fec8:aedf/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip r s -

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto static metric 600
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.111 metric 600
192.168.2.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.22
```

192.168.1.110/24 was an IP address I used for the ethernet NIC previously. Ive deleated it and still issue presists.

There was also another route for both wifi and ethernet to go the gateway, I delated the ethernet route.

Comment: you seem to be using 2 network (192.168.**1**.X and 192.168.**2**.X), did you set forwarding ? can you edit your post with result of `ip a s` and `ip r s` ?

Comment: yes 1 network for the ethernet NIC and one for the wifi NIC, this was advised by one poster on a thread were similar issues to what I am having.  no I did not set forwarding learned 2 new commands today, cheers!

Comment: So I guess 192.168.2.X IP are manualy set, and 192.168.1.X are given via DHCP by your router ? IP 192.168.1.110 should be deleted (if manually set), is your camera using wifi or wire (i.e. network cable) ?

Comment: for IP forwarding, see my answer in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/121621/setting-up-a-bridged-access-point-on-a-raspberry-pi

Comment: Thanks, so I think I found the issue, I had made a backup if the yaml configuration files in that directory. I don't have a strong eneough understanding on how they were loaded but obviously now it loads all files in that directory regardless of filename. Hence I had 2 config files with different static ips assigned to my ethenet nic. Its all working now. Thanks for replying